# How to approach this logic question?

Tags: logic

What valid conclusion can be drawn from the premises of the following arguments, paraphrased from logician Lewis Carroll? Explain your answer.
a. Every sane person can do logic; no insane person can serve on a jury;
none of your friends can do logic; therefore, ··

We can use semantic tableaux to check if its true relative to the premises,but this is the opposite?how to predict valid conclusion from true premises.

Comment: Well, what do you think the justifiable conclusion is?

Comment: If the premise is true and the rules of inference are sound,then the conclusion must also be true ,i  want to check whether the answer is unique or not.

Comment: There is no unique conclusion.  One could conclude that "every sane person can do logic".  That (obviously) follows from the  given premises, though I doubt it was the intended conclusion.  Again, what do you imagine the intended conclusion to be?

Comment: Every of my friends cannot serve on jury ,is that right?

Comment: Well, the grammar is a bit off, but more or less, yes.  "None of my friends can serve on juries."  Can you see how to justify that?

Comment: ok got it,thanks